# Printing the value of a global variable and then changing the value in python

Tags: python, global-variables, interpreter

The global keyword is used in a function to refer to a global variable within that function and modify it. However even if the global keyword is not used and  if we just try to print the variable, python assumes it is the global variable that is being referred and simply prints that like so.

```
a = 2
def foo():
    print(a)
foo()
```

the above code outputs 2. But the following code throws an error.

```
a = 2
def foo():
    print(a)
    a = 3
foo()
```

I get an UnboundLocalError saying local variable 'a' was referenced before assignment. Now since python is an interpreted language and execution happens one line at a time, shouldn't it first print the global value of a which is 2 (like in the first case) and then create a local variable with the same name ans assign it to 3. In the second case how does the interpreter know right at the print statement that I am referring to another variable 'a' in the next line? Why doesn't it behave in the same way as above?

PS: I do understand that using the global keyword can help me change the value of a from 2 to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python *byte code* is interpreted; Python source is first *compiled* to byte code.

Names are either local or global within a single scope, and that determination is made at compile time; you can't switch half way through a fuction. If there is *any* assignment to `a` in the function, it is local *everywhere* in the function unless you use `global a`.

```
a = 2
def foo():
    global a
    print(a)
    a = 3
```

Without the global statement, `print(a)` refers to the local name `a`, even though it occurs before the actual assignment.

Comment: >Python byte code is interpreted; Python source is first compiled to byte code.

So that means when the source code is first compiled , this resolution of whether a particular variable belongs to the local or global scope happens (not necessarily in a line by line manner) and once the byte code is generated , the line by line execution begins. And since the code was first compiled first, the judgment was already made on whether a particular variable's scope is being changed halfway through in a function and hence the line by line execution of the byte code doesn't matter much? Am i right?

Comment: Correct. Even if you want to use a mental model of interpretation, it's best to think of the code as being evaluated *statement by statement*, rather than *line by line*, and `def` introduces a single, multi-line statement. Part of the execution of that statement is to determine which names in the body of the `def` statement are global and which are local, so that when the body is executed when the function is *called*,  each name has a precise, uniform meaning.

Comment: Going back to compilation, though, local and global names are handled by different byte codes, so you need to determine which a name is before you can generate the byte code for a function.